# Clicking a window to select it, and again to do something

Tags: macos, window

In windows you have all windows constantly "selected", so you say you are in chrome, to pause a song in Spotify you just click the pause button. On Mac OS if you click it just selects the window first, then you have to click again to actually interact with it. is there any way to disable this and make everything work when you click it?

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably have to look for a system-level hack. SIMBL plugins come to mind, though I am not sure whether they still work in current OS X (10.12). I would start here: https://github.com/w0lfschild/mySIMBL .

Note however that Apple has been making SIMBL-like hacks more and more difficult for security reasons. Read a bit about what's involved before going that route.

Some discussion and details on OS X's clicking behavior at https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/34446/enable-click-through-preferrably-for-all-applications